# WebRtc - MediaRecorder causing spike in CPU, laggy video

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webrtc, webm

I have a stream via `getUserMedia` that I have attached both a `PeerConnection` to (for streaming) - as well as two instances of `MediaRecorder`.  Without mediaRecorder, everything runs smoothly.

With the one or two instances of MediaRecorder attached to the stream (chrome latest, webm) I get large spike in both my CPU consumption and chrome's `GPU Process`, leading to both choppy video and choppy streaming.

[image]

I'm using `mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8"` for my MediaRecorder/s.  Given that I'm on an i7, this seems a little disproportionate to the work that's being done.  Are there any configs/tweaks/best practices that might help improve performance here?

Or perhaps some more information I can dig up to shed a bit more light on what's happening? FYI if I stub out MediaRecorder I don't see the spikes or performance degradation, so it is indeed the culprit.

My code looks like this:

```
// enter streaming module
// set private stream to the media stream we pass in
// attach two media recorders to that stream
// call requestData on both streams every five seconds (my data handling is not the culprit)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it with extensions disabled e.g. in a private window?

Comment: @wOxxOm - yes this is with incognito

Comment: Not sure it's possible to solve without inspecting/debugging/profiling the actual code. It can be a bug in Chrome, try submitting a reproducible test case on https://crbug.com

Comment: @SB2055 did you find out how to improve this? Should I assume that recording smooth videos is a matter of CPU rather than GPU?

Comment: @SB2055 did you find any settings which can prevent this problem? One of our users reported a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Video encoding is heavyweight work.  What you're experiencing here is normal.

If you go to `chrome://gpu/`, under "Video Acceleration Information" you can determine which codecs are hardware accelerated on your platform.  Hardware accelerated codecs will lighten your CPU load, but aren't always available.